# Hibernate unable to validate ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have this parameter in my class:

```
@Past
private ZonedDateTime activityDate;
```

When trying to save to DB the following exception is thrown:

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.time.ZonedDateTime.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.verifyResolveWasUnique(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.findMatchingValidatorClass(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:547)
```

Can anyone please explain why this is happening and is there a way to get this to work? Or do I need to manually validate ZonedDateTime?

To be sure I have both org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.0.3.Final and org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:5.0.3.Final on my classpath which are currently the latest-greatest.

Comment: What version of Hibernate Validator do you have? It should be at least 5.2 in order to use Java 8 types (see: http://in.relation.to/2014/10/23/hibernate-validator-520-alpha-1-with-java-8-support-and-a-51-maintenance-release/)

Comment: @R4J - That was the problem, I did not have a validator in my classpath. I put the latest version 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.2.0.Final'
in and it started working. If you would like to put that in as the answer I will go ahead and mark it as correct.

Comment: Naah, no need. I am just glad that my question has lead you to a resolution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R4J's comment led me to the correct answer. It was throwing the exception because I did not have the hibernate-validator (or any Validator interface for that matter) on my classpath. Adding the latest release got this working for me and I post this update in case anyone else makes the same mistake I did.